# How can I extract a key value without loading entire json file

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I got a list of huge JSON files is it possible to extract key values without loading entire json files in python requests.
[This is how it looks](https://blockchain.info/block-height/691000)

Comment: GSON is a library, which can handle big files. It maybe doesn't help you, but I want to mention the file you posted is 1.8MB large, which is definitely handable without problems.

Comment: @Jakob GSON is a Java library - isnt it? See https://github.com/google/gson

Comment: @balderman Sorry, you're right XD My brain was just in Java mode. But 1.8MB is still handable for python without problems.

Comment: @Jakob I have to iterate through hundreds of thousands of json so loading each and every file might be time consuming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an incremental JSON parser or streaming JSON parser such as [yajl-py](https://github.com/pykler/yajl-py). However, it will always start from the beginning, so if your key is to the very end of the file, this approach won't help much with respect to loading from disk or network.

All JSON content up to the key must have passed the parser's memory, but it's not all in memory at one time.

As mentioned by @Jacob in the comments, I would not consider 1.8 MB as a "huge" file. I was working on files in several GB range already. That's definitely a point where you need to consider running out of physical RAM.

Comment: Luckily its on top

Comment: I have to iterate through hundreds of thousands of json so loading each and every file might be time consuming

Comment: In that case, the incremental parser could really help.